# Senha e redirecionamento

Tags: php

estou tentando criar um site que possui uma página, onde o usuário precisa inserir uma senha, depois de inserida a senha, caso correta ele redireciona o usuário para uma home page, caso contrário exibe uma mensagem de erro, não sei exatamente oq está dando errado, já que quando clico no botão eu apenas sou redirecionado para a página php que aparece logo a msg de erro.

Formulário index.html:

```
<form id="formPassword" action="php/verificar.php" method="POST">

                    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 

                    <label for="password">Password:</label>

                    <input id='password' type='password' name="password" size='15' maxlength='15' onfocus="value=''"/>

                    <br>
                    <br>

                    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp

                    <input id='button' src='images/enter_button.png' onmouseover="this.src='images/enter_button_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/enter_button.png'" alt='Enter' type='image' width='150px' height='30px'/>

                </form>
```

página php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>

        </title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

            $password = $_POST['password'];

            if($password=="senha"){
                include("home.php"); 
            }else{
                echo "<p>Username or Password not entered correctly please try again.</p>"; 
            }

        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: aqui o código html:

Answer (score 3):

Tenta colocar o type do seu botão lá no form como submit. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ponha a sua verificação para a página na qual está. Exemplo:

**index.php**:

```
<!-- Trabalhe sempre com arquivos .php para poder executar as condições-->
<form id="formPassword" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" type='password' name="password" size="15" maxlength='15' onfocus="value=""/>

    <!-- Seu botão deve ser do tipo: submit e NÃO IMAGE e use SEMPRE aspas duplas para os atributos do input -->
    <input id="button" src="images/enter_button.png" onmouseover="this.src=images/enter_button_hover.png" onmouseout="this.src=images/enter_button.png" alt="Enter" type="submit" width="150px" height="30px"/>
</form>

<?php

/*Logo abaixo crie sua condição que receberá a requisição via POST e validará a senha, conforme você mesmo fez: */ 

   //Se houver uma requisição do tipe POST com um valor para password
  if(isset($_POST['password'])){
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($password=="senha"){
       //Aqui faça um redirecionamento, uma vez que a senha está correta.
            header('location: home.php'); 
        }else{
            echo "<p>Senha incorreta! Tente novamente.</p>"; 
        }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Somente codificando o que o Jefferson respondeu seria assim:

```
<input id='submit' src='images/enter_button.png' onmouseover="this.src='images/enter_button_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/enter_button.png'" alt='Enter' type='image' width='150px' height='30px'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Em seu botão coloque o type como `submit`

```
<input id='submit' src='images/enter_button.png' onmouseover="this.src='images/enter_button_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/enter_button.png'" alt='Enter' type='submit' width='150px' height='30px'/>
```

No arquivo `validar.php` ao inves de usar `include("home.php");`
use `header('location: home.php');`

quando você usa `include` é como se voce estivesse carregando o arquivo `home.php` na propria pagina `validar.php` e é por isso que o usuario não é redirecionado, já usando `header('location: nomeDaSuaPagina')` significa que você esta modificando o cabeçalho da requisição `HTTP` e trocando a localização da pagina para a sua pagina em questão.

Caso queira exibir uma mensagem de `login  e/ou senha invalidos` no proprio form vá ate seu arquivo `validar.php` e na condição `else` coloque:

```
$msg = 'Login ou senha incorretos';
header('location: index.php');  // Troque o index para o nome da sua pagina de login
```

Logo antes do formulario de login insira:

```
<?php if (isset($msg)) { echo $msg }; ?>
// Este trecho verifica se a variavel $msg contem algum valor e caso contenha exibi o valor armazenado nela.
```